# scapy Uses Wrong Sender MAC and IP Address for sr1()

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, arp

My `ARP request` packet is sent from a thread running from a PyQt5 GUI app.

When I

- Connect WiFi
- Launch the app
- Send the packet `packet = ARP(op='who-has', pdst='192.168.1.1')`
- `packet.show()` outputs:

```
###[ ARP ]### 
  hwtype    = 0x1
  ptype     = IPv4
  hwlen     = None
  plen      = None
  op        = who-has
  hwsrc     = ......:aa:bb:cc      <--- This is OK, the correct one (wlan0)
  psrc      = 192.168.1.112
  hwdst     = None
  pdst      = 192.168.1.1
```

and `sr1(packet)` succeeds.

But when

- Disconnect WiFi
- Launch the app
- Connect WiFi
- Send the packet `packet = ARP(op='who-has', pdst='192.168.1.1')`
- `packet.show()` outputs:

```
###[ ARP ]### 
  hwtype    = 0x1
  ptype     = IPv4
  hwlen     = None
  plen      = None
  op        = who-has
  hwsrc     = ......:19:b6:dd    <--- This is wrong one (eth0)
  psrc      = 0.0.0.0
  hwdst     = None
  pdst      = 192.168.1.1
```

and `sr1(packet)` fails.

Notice that `hwsrc` is now changed to my `wired ethernet` which has cable disconnected and the `psrc` is set to `0.0.0.0` which is not my WiFi IP.

In fact, it is not using the default route after I connect to WiFi, rather, it uses another interface instead of the `wlan0` (although the default route is via `wlan0`).

My Question is: Should not `scapy` use the default route (i.e. wlan0) to send ARP request after I connect to WiFi ?

If I exit and relaunch the app keeping WiFi connected it works well.

Now I need a solution to send ARP request from wlan0 interface although I connect WiFi after the app is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scapy crafts its own packet headers, so it needs to perform routing table lookups on its own as well. Unfortunately, it only reads the whole OS routing table *on startup* and always uses the cached information from that point on. You can see the table in `conf.route`.

Use `conf.route.resync()` every time you switch connections.

Comment: Well, after calling `conf.route.resync()` it uses the correct `psrc` but wrong `hwsrc`, as a result `sr1()` fails.